# Ruby on Rails js is broken

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, windows

I've recently gotten back into Ruby and its finally working for me. That is, until I try to include js.

This error shows up all the time, and at first deleting the line mentioned worked

```
Showing C:/Users/1/2/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:
SyntaxError: [stdin]:1:18: reserved word "function"
Rails.root: C:/Users/1/2
```

But that doesn't fix the issue, and I need to use javascript in my project.
I've tried changing

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

to

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

but then javascript doesn't work

I've tried installing node, and node works. Javascript still doesn't.
I've tried messing with my runtimes.rb

```
    JScript = ExternalRuntime.new(
 :name        => "JScript",
 :command     => "cscript //E:jscript //Nologo",
 :runner_path => ExecJS.root + "/support/jscript_runner.js",
 :encoding    => 'UTF-8' # CScript with //U returns UTF-16LE
)
```

I've tried

```
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
```

And still nothing

I was really hoping nodejs would help but it didn't.

Application.js:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which        will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts,    vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced    here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

welcome.coffee:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){
   $('nav').addClass("sticky");
   $('#title').addClass("sticky");
   $('a').addClass("sticky");
   $('input').addClass("sticky");
  }
  else{
    $('nav').removeClass("sticky");
    $('#title').removeClass("sticky");
    $('a').removeClass("sticky");
    $('input').removeClass("sticky");
  }
});
alert('Hello, World!');
```

Application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>App title</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
 </head>
 <body>

  <%= yield %>

 </body>
</html>
```

welcome_controller.rb

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

Comment: can u paste the content of the JS file?

Comment: What's in your `application.js` and the files it includes? You sure it's not just a JS error, like using the word `function` as a variable name?

Comment: I did a simple alert('Hello World to debug'); in my coffee-script. Edited my question to include application.js

Comment: So, what's in *your* JS files (e.g., not the Rails JS files) you're including? I don't understand how you expect people to help. Pretty sure Mu and I are thinking the same thing here.

Comment: My welcome module has a welcome.coffee file. I put my alert in there as per the instructions in application.js

Comment: So maybe posting that file would be helpful?

Comment: Its blank with the code alert('hello world'); thought I made that clear

Comment: I added multiple code blocks related to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your welcome.coffee, that's not coffeescript.  Here is the coffeescript equivalent:

```
$(window).scroll ->
  if $(this).scrollTop() > 1
    $('nav').addClass 'sticky'
    $('#title').addClass 'sticky'
    $('a').addClass 'sticky'
    $('input').addClass 'sticky'
  else
    $('nav').removeClass 'sticky'
    $('#title').removeClass 'sticky'
    $('a').removeClass 'sticky'
    $('input').removeClass 'sticky'
  return
alert 'Hello, World!'
```

You had javascript where it was expecting coffeescript.  It was complaining because it failed to parse the file with a syntax error saying function is a javascript keyward.  Coffeescript compiler no likey.

Comment: Thank you so much! I wish did more research on coffeescript instead of the literal error. I spent hours looking for the solution. Again, thank you so much!